# Numpy convert list of 3D variable size volumes to 4D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, 3d, 4d

I'm working on a neural network where I am augmenting data via rotation and varying the size of each input volume.

Let me back up, the input to the network is a 3D volume. I generate variable size 3D volumes, and then pad each volume with zero's such that the input volume is constant. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38963610/numpy-padding-4d-units-with-all-zeros/38964707#38964707) for an issue I was having with padding (now resolved).

I generate a variable size 3D volume, append it to a list, and then convert the list into a numpy array. At this point, padding hasn't occured so converting it into a 4D tuple makes no sense...

```
input_augmented_matrix = []
label_augmented_matrix = []
for i in range(n_volumes):
    if i % 50 == 0:
        print ("Augmenting step #" + str(i))
    slice_index = randint(0,n_input)
    z_max = randint(5,n_input)
    z_rand = randint(3,5)
    z_min = z_max - z_rand
    x_max = randint(75, n_input_x)
    x_rand = randint(60, 75)
    x_min = x_max - x_rand
    y_max = randint(75, n_input_y)
    y_rand = randint(60, 75)
    y_min = y_max - y_rand
    random_rotation = randint(1,4) * 90
    for j in range(2):
        temp_volume = np.empty((z_rand, x_rand, y_rand))
        k = 0
        for z in range(z_min, z_max):
            l = 0
            for x in range(x_min, x_max):
                m = 0
                for y in range(y_min, y_max):
                    if j == 0:
                        #input volume
                        try:
                            temp_volume[k][l][m] = input_matrix[z][x][y]
                        except:
                            pdb.set_trace()
                    else:
                        #ground truth volume
                        temp_volume[k][l][m] = label_matrix[z][x][y]
                    m = m + 1
                l = l + 1
            k = k + 1
        temp_volume = np.asarray(temp_volume)
        temp_volume = np.rot90(temp_volume,random_rotation)
        if j == 0:
            input_augmented_matrix.append(temp_volume)
        else:
            label_augmented_matrix.append(temp_volume)

input_augmented_matrix = np.asarray(input_augmented_matrix)
label_augmented_matrix = np.asarray(label_augmented_matrix)
```

The dimensions of `input_augmented_matrix` at this point is `(N,)`

Then I pad with the following code...

```
for i in range(n_volumes):
    print("Padding volume #" + str(i))
    input_augmented_matrix[i] = np.lib.pad(input_augmented_matrix[i], ((0,n_input_z - int(input_augmented_matrix[i][:,0,0].shape[0])),
                                                (0,n_input_x - int(input_augmented_matrix[i][0,:,0].shape[0])),
                                                (0,n_input_y - int(input_augmented_matrix[i][0,0,:].shape[0]))),
                                'constant', constant_values=0)
    label_augmented_matrix[i] = np.lib.pad(label_augmented_matrix[i], ((0,n_input_z - int(label_augmented_matrix[i][:,0,0].shape[0])),
                                                (0,n_input_x - int(label_augmented_matrix[i][0,:,0].shape[0])),
                                                (0,n_input_y - int(label_augmented_matrix[i][0,0,:].shape[0]))),
                                'constant', constant_values=0)
```

At this point, the dimensions are still `(N,)` even though every element of the list is constant. For example `input_augmented_matrix[0] = input_augmented_matrix[1]`

Currently I just loop through and create a new array, but it takes too long and I would prefer some sort of method that automates this. I do it with the following code...

```
input_4d = np.empty((n_volumes, n_input_z, n_input_x, n_input_y))
label_4d = np.empty((n_volumes, n_input_z, n_input_x, n_input_y))
for i in range(n_volumes):
    print("Converting to 4D tuple #" + str(i))
    for j in range(n_input_z):
        for k in range(n_input_x):
            for l in range(n_input_y):
                input_4d[i][j][k][l] = input_augmented_matrix[i][j][k][l]
                label_4d[i][j][k][l] = label_augmented_matrix[i][j][k][l]
```

Is there a cleaner and faster way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understood this part

```
k = 0
for z in range(z_min, z_max):
    l = 0
    for x in range(x_min, x_max):
        m = 0
        for y in range(y_min, y_max):
            if j == 0:
                #input volume
                try:
                    temp_volume[k][l][m] = input_matrix[z][x][y]
                except:
                    pdb.set_trace()
            else:
                #ground truth volume
                temp_volume[k][l][m] = label_matrix[z][x][y]
            m = m + 1
        l = l + 1
    k = k + 1
```

You just want to do this

```
temp_input = input_matrix[z_min:z_max, x_min:x_max, y_min:y_max]
temp_label = label_matrix[z_min:z_max, x_min:x_max, y_min:y_max]
```

and then

```
temp_input = np.rot90(temp_input, random_rotation)
temp_label = np.rot90(temp_label, random_rotation)

input_augmented_matrix.append(temp_input)
label_augmented_matrix.append(temp_label)
```

Here

```
input_augmented_matrix[i] = np.lib.pad(
    input_augmented_matrix[i],
    ((0,n_input_z - int(input_augmented_matrix[i][:,0,0].shape[0])),
     (0,n_input_x - int(input_augmented_matrix[i][0,:,0].shape[0])),
     (0,n_input_y - int(input_augmented_matrix[i][0,0,:].shape[0]))),
    'constant', constant_values=0)
```

Better to do this, because `shape` property gives you size of array by all dimensions

```
ia_shape = input_augmented_matrix[i].shape
input_augmented_matrix[i] = np.lib.pad(
    input_augmented_matrix[i],
    ((0, n_input_z - ia_shape[0]),
     (0, n_input_x - ia_shape[1])),
     (0, n_input_y - ia_shape[2]))),
    'constant',
    constant_values=0)
```

I guess now you're ready to refactor the last part of your code with magic indexing of `NumPy`.

My common suggestions:

- use functions for repeated parts of code to avoid such indents like in your cascade of loops;
- if you need so lot of nested loops, think about recursion, if you can't deal without them;
- explore abilities of `NumPy` in official [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/contents.html): they're really exciting ;) For example, [indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html) is helpful for this task;
- use `PyLint` and `Flake8` packages to inspect quality of your code.

Do you want to write neural network by yourself, or you just want to solve some patterns recognition task? [SciPy](https://www.scipy.org/) library may contain what you need and it's based on `NumPy`.

Comment: thanks for the help! this looks much better :) and this is a data class for a tensorflow network

Comment: @KendallWeihe you're welcome! Does it solve your issue or I've missed something?